# WPF UI not updated upon property change

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

I have a custom HashTable that has a method that allows someone to delete a "partNumber" (a value) from the HashTable.

The delete method is as follows:

```
class COSC202HashTable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //....
    private List<int> underlyingList;
    //... 
    public List<int> HashList { get { return underlyingList; } }

    public void Delete(int partNumber)
    {
            string theAlgoritnm = Algorithm;
            if (String.Compare(theAlgoritnm, "Modulo Division") == 0 && String.Compare(Probe, "Linear Collision Resolution") == 0)
            {
                LinearModularDivision(partNumber, false);
            }
            if (String.Compare(theAlgoritnm, "Modulo Division") == 0 && String.Compare(Probe, "Key Offset Collision Resolution") == 0)
            {
                KeyOffsetModularDivision(partNumber, false);
            }
            if (String.Compare(theAlgoritnm, "Pseudorandom") == 0)
            {
                Pseudorandom(partNumber, false);
            }
            if (String.Compare(theAlgoritnm, "Rotation") == 0)
            {
                Rotation(partNumber, false);
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("HashList");
    }
   //.......
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

I am binding the HashTable's underlying values to the UI; however the UI is not being updated after a value is deleted. I made sure that there are no problems with spelling etc...

This is the markup I have for my WPF UI:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <COSC202:COSC202HashTable x:Name="TheHashTable"  x:Key="TheHashTable" PropertyChanged="TheHashTable_PropertyChanged"></COSC202:COSC202HashTable>
</Window.Resources>
<ListView x:Name="HashResults" Height="32" Width="1200" Margin="10"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource TheHashTable}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=HashList}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    <ListView.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,2">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0"></GradientStop>
            <GradientStop Color="DarkBlue" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ListView.Background>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" FontSize="11" Foreground="Azure" VerticalAlignment="Top" ></TextBlock>
                <Label Content="|" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="5"></Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This is the code that I am calling to delete the item in the HashTable upon button click:

```
  private void DeleteItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Object item = HashResults.SelectedItem;
            COSC202HashTable theHashTable = (COSC202HashTable)this.Resources["TheHashTable"];
            if (theHashTable != null && item != null)
            {
                theHashTable.Delete((int)item);
            }
            HashResults.SelectedIndex = -1;

        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

-Frinny

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why are you using `String.Compare()` instead of `==`?

Comment: Because that's the way I'm used to doing things. I mainly work with VB.NET and I have found this to be the best way to compare strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first place to look for binding errors in the Output window, this quite often will point you in the right direction.

If you are binding to a custom collection then you may need to implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx). Or consider changing your data source to ObservableCollection, or in your case you may need [ObservableDictionary](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/).

Also you mentioned spelling errors, there are a couple of ways to ensure that this is not an issue, check out [MVVM Foundation](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/)'s base ObservableObject

Your code is missing a few details, such as your declaration for the StaticResource TheHashTable.

Edit:
Raising PropertyChanged against a List class will not notify of changes within that List, if you need the UI to see changes within the list change the list type to ObservableCollection or create a new property:

```
public ObservableCollection Hash
{
  get
  {
    return new ObservableCollection(this.HashList);
  }
}
```

and bind to the Hash property.

Comment: I am not binding to a custom collection. I am binding to a custom HashTable class. The values for this HashTable are stored in a List<int>....I don't think that the INotifyCollectionChanged will help me in this case but thank you for this information because I didn't know about this interface before you posted it.  I have modified my original post to contain the XAML declaration of TheHashTable.

Comment: I just ran it again and there are no errors in the Output window.

Comment: I've also updated my original post so that it shows more implementation for the custom HashTable class that I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to implement the [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) interface on your collection.